# How to avoid refreshing table after populating form details in adf

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a af:table and af:panelformlayout representing the same VO in a fragment.The details populated in the form will be updated in the af:table. The form has 10 fields. Each time I fill in a form field the af:table gets updated and refreshed.

My question is how do i avoid table refresh after populating each field in the form. I want the table to refresh only after i fill all the fields and submit the details.

I am using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might need to adjust PPR: 
[here](https://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2014/07/smart-auto-ppr-change-event-policy.html), [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16764_01/web.1111/b31973/af_ppr.htm), or [overview](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/adf/jellema-muir-adf-089011.html), [tutorial - how to make it happen](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/simpler-partial-page-refresh-ppr-with-dependent-fields) - so maybe how to "turn it off"

Comment: Thanks Joe for your response. Setting autoSubmit to false resolved the issue.